# Как выбрать потомка элемента?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Имеется такой кусок кода:

```
                        <div class="like cbutton cbutton--effect-boris" data-id="1">
                        <!--<img src="/images/svg/look/like.svg" height="25">-->


                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="25" height="25" viewBox="0 0 50 50" style="display: inline-block;vertical-align: middle;height: 25px;width: 25px;">
<path style="text-indent:0;text-align:start;line-height:normal;text-transform:none;block-progression:tb;-inkscape-font-specification:Bitstream Vera Sans" d="M 16.375 9 C 10.115452 9 5 14.056532 5 20.28125 C 5 33.048861 19.486343 39.737709 24.375 43.78125 L 25 44.3125 L 25.625 43.78125 C 30.513657 39.737709 45 33.048861 45 20.28125 C 45 14.056532 39.883642 9 33.625 9 C 30.149687 9 27.086018 10.611908 25 13.0625 C 22.914613 10.611757 19.850313 9 16.375 9 z M 16.375 11 C 19.642305 11 22.480134 12.65201 24.15625 15.15625 L 25 16.40625 L 25.84375 15.15625 C 27.52092 12.651785 30.357695 11 33.625 11 C 38.810358 11 43 15.145968 43 20.28125 C 43 31.180298 30.739443 37.287299 25 41.78125 C 19.260557 37.287299 7 31.180298 7 20.28125 C 7 15.145968 11.188548 11 16.375 11 z" color="#000" overflow="visible" enable-background="accumulate" font-family="Bitstream Vera Sans"></path></svg>

                        <?php
                            $data = parse_ini_file("look/likes.ini"); // Парсим INI-файл    
                            $likes = $data[1]; // Получаем количество лайков у статьи
                        ?>
                        <span><?=$likes?></span>
                    </div>
```

и такой js

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".like").bind("click", function (event) {
        var that = $(this);

        if (get_cookie("VoiceLook"+that.attr("data-id")) != "Yes") {
            $.ajax({
                url: "look/like.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: ("id=" + that.attr("data-id")),
                dataType: "text",
                success: function (result) {
                    if (result) {
                        //that.text(Number(that.text()) + 1);

                        that.children().text(Number(that.text()) + 1);
                    } else alert("Error");
                }
            });
            document.cookie = "VoiceLook"+that.attr("data-id")+"=Yes";
        }
        else{       
            alert("Вы уже голосовали за этот проект!");
        }
    });
});


function get_cookie(cookie_name) {
    var results = document.cookie.match('(^|;) ?' + cookie_name + '=([^;]*)(;|$)');
    if (results)
        return (unescape(results[2]));
    else
        return null;
}
```

При нажатии на .like мы начинаем работать с ним. Подскажите пожалуйста, как в процессе мне работать не с .like, а с span и svg внутри класса. that.children() не помогает.

Comment: `this`  у тебя в обработчике уже не `.like` , там идет потеря контекста.
Тупо в консоль выведи, посмотри чему равен `this`
Как вариант можно использовать `event.target` и уже у него смотреть детей.

Comment: `that.children().get(0)` - svg, `that.children().get(1)` - span ..... соответственно `that.children().get(1).innerText` - текст из спана, например....`that.data().id` - номер из датасета `data` дива и т.д.

Comment: @pepel_xD расскажешь с чего там потеря контекста? откуда ей там взяться? и на что оно там, по-вашему, заменяется?

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский вы правы.С помощью that.children().get(1).innerText я занес текст в переменную и редактировал её. Теперь мне надо перезаписать текст в спане на редактированную переменную. Как можно это сделать? Как то с set?

Comment: @Максим да не...какой сет.... просто `that.children().get(1).innerText = '666';` ......и чтоб длинные строки не писать постоянно, вынесите в переменную `var span = that.children().get(1);`  и далее `span.innerText` - возьмет текст, `span.innerText = 666;` установит текст